# '@io_bazel_rules_docker//toolchains/docker': Unable to load file '@bazel_skylib//:bzl_library.bzl': file doesn't exist

Tags: docker, dependencies, bazel

i've tried to load io_bazel_rules_docker to push a container i have in bazel. And the thing that have me stuck is the bazel_skylib dependency.

The error is that is not found, i've tried everything, adding it to my Workspace, copying it in my directory and it doesn't work. This is my Workspace part where i declare it.

```
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_skylib",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.0.3/bazel-skylib-1.0.3.tar.gz",
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/releases/download/1.0.3/bazel-skylib-1.0.3.tar.gz",
    ],
    sha256 = "1c531376ac7e5a180e0237938a2536de0c54d93f5c278634818e0efc952dd56c",
)
load("@bazel_skylib//:workspace.bzl", "bazel_skylib_workspace")
bazel_skylib_workspace()

git_repository(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    remote = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker.git",
    tag = "v0.7.0"
)

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//java:image.bzl",
    _java_image_repos = "repositories",
```

)

This is the error that i have:

```
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target ******: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '@io_bazel_rules_docker//toolchains/docker': Unable to load file '@bazel_skylib//:bzl_library.bzl': file doesn't exist
ERROR: Analysis of target '******' failed; build aborted: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '@io_bazel_rules_docker//toolchains/docker': Unable to load file '@bazel_skylib//:bzl_library.bzl': file doesn't exist
```

I've removed the bazel skylib declaration and is the same error. Still don't know what to do.

Comment: Which Bazel version do you use? Maybe some other external repository has already loaded an older `bazel_skylib`? To ensure it move the `bazel_skylib` definition to the `WORKSPACE` file top. Also you could just remove the `bazel_skylib` definition, because `io_bazel_rules_docker` already load it

Comment: I've tried with different versions such as, 0.27, 1.0.0 and 4.0.0. In all the same error. And yes, i've removed finally the bazel_skylib declaration from my WORKSPACE file, but it still complains about the missing file. I'll give a try to a different versions of io_baze_rules_docker and i'll tell you.

Comment: Yeah, it is hard to find a proper version combination for Bazel rules. For sake of sanity use the latest one